# Format IPv4 string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing an Angular 5 directive that validates an IPv4 input as the user types into it.

Currently it works as expected, however it's pretty verbose:

```javascript
this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value
  .replace(/^\D+/, '') // Remove any non-digit from position 0
  .replace(/[^\d\.]+/, '') // Remove any non-digit, non dot from string
  .replace(/\.{2,}/, '.') // Force sequences of dots into one single dot
  .split('.').map(seq => seq.substring(0, 3)) // Limit to {1-3} digits per group
  .slice(0, 4) // Limit to 4 groups of digits
  .join('.') // Turn back into string and give dots back
```

How could I replace the `split`-`map`-`slice`-`join` sequence with another RegExp or string method in JavaScript?

Comment: The question I got in mind is: do you want to validate or to validate and manipulate? Do you want to show an error message when the user enters a non valid character or directly remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Your request is a bit complicated let say fault tolerant. So given
    "asdf1.2.3.aaa...4afd"
you are expected to get: "1.2.3.4".

The fist replace (.replace(/^\D+/, '')) seems to be superfluous because of the second replace. And the whole expression might be

```
var original = "asdf1.2.3.aaa...4afd";
var formatted = original.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "")
            .replace(/^\.*(\d+)\.+(\d+)\.+(\d+)\.+(\d+)[^\d]?.*$/g, "$1.$2.$3.$4");
```

Note that this will give different result to non IPv4 strings. Like "1.2.3" so you may want to test this code as:

```
        var a = "asdf1.2.3.aaa...4afd";
        var a = "asdf2.3.aaa...4.5.6af.7d";
        var a = "1.2.3.4";
        var a = "1.2.3";
        var a = "1.2";
        var b = a.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
        var c = b.replace(/^\.*(\d+)\.+(\d+)\.+(\d+)\.+(\d+)[^\d]?.*$/g, "$1.$2.$3.$4");
        console.log(a + "  " + b + "  " + c);
```